# Bounding Box ob Objects change to Circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I would like to know if there is actually the possibility to have a circle bounding box and  if i can give this area a background color?

If it is not possible can someone tell me where i could change something in the source to get circle bounding box?

I saw this discussion was once a year ago and maybe something changed in this direction although i couldn't find anything in the docs.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: i mean the source of the actual fabric 1.4.0 version. i do not actually know where i could add or modify to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

The bounding box of a circle is a square that exactly contains that circle.

So you can create a rectangle with its center at the center of the circle and its width and height equal to twice the circle's radius.

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: CircleCenterXMinusCircleRadius,
  top: CircleCenterYMinusCircleRadius,
  fill: "red",
  width: CircleRadiusX2,
  height: CircleRadiusX2
});
```

...or do you mean you want to set the fill color of a circle

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    fill: 'blue',
    // other properties here 
});
```

...or do you want to set the fill color of the canvas background:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvasElement', {
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(100,100,200)',
  // other properties here
});
```

Comment: Many Thanks for answering.
What i have: The User can create via click/touch many circles on the canvas. Each Circle has a "bounding area" where you can move that circle right? this area i want to be a circle instead a rect. and the possibility to color the area. but this should only be visible if the object is active, like the normal controls and border. does this make sense?

many thanks for helping me out

Comment: I understand.  No, you cannot customize the controls associated with an element to make the controls circular instead of rectangular.

Comment: Hey. I dont want to change the controls itself i want to change the bounding box to be a circle instead of a rect. Is there a possibilty to add some properties to active elements on the canvas? Cause then i could create just a bigger circle around the original one. Anyone have experiences with that? Would be very much helpful.

Comment: Sure. You can create a group containing smaller & larger concentric circles.  The larger concentric circle would be your `bounding circle`. Study up on groups here:  https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Working-with-groups

Comment: hey. that sounds like what i want. but i have to serialize all my objects to restore it for the user at another point and i don't want to store the larger concentric circle. i just want to show it up for moving if the smaller circle is active and if not it should be not visible and not be in json string. do you know what i mean? is this possible as well? many thanks

Comment: Yes. Remove the larger circle before serializing.  Add the larger circle back after deserializing and reinstantiating.

Comment: hey. do you know how i can scale only one object in a group of objects? in my specific case the inner circle should scale till a maxwidth/maxheight and the outer circle should always have the same size? would be great to get an answer on that. many thanks